# Searching for a particular string using Regex in Bash/Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

I am trying to echo out the the average round trip time for 4 ICMP echo/echo rely packets (in ms) for a website like google. This is my code as of now.

```
echo "$(ping -c 4 google.com | grep '??????')"
```

Pinging the website works but I have no idea how to echo out only the average round trip time. I have only used Regex for validation on web forms, but I haven't used it in awhile. I assume I can use Regex to find only what I am searching for, but if there is a better way of doing this, that would also be great. I am writing this using shell scripting for linux ubuntu

This is an example of the output. The only part of this I need is the part at the bottom where it says `rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.556/14.579/14.614/0.088 ms`.

```
PING google.com (142.250.74.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par10s40-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=108 tim                                                                                                                                                                             e=14.5 ms
64 bytes from par10s40-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=108 tim                                                                                                                                                                             e=14.5 ms
64 bytes from par10s40-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=108 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from par10s40-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.238): icmp_seq=4 ttl=108 time=14.6 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.556/14.579/14.614/0.088 ms
```

Comment: What's the `ping` output look like?

Comment: ill edit the question. the message is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `ping` output looks like the following:

```
$ ping -c 4 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.14.238): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.14.238: icmp_seq=0 ttl=118 time=78.019 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.238: icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=62.416 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.238: icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=63.019 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.238: icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=62.415 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 62.415/66.467/78.019/6.674 ms
```

In this scenario the average time is `66.467` (ms)

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '/avg/ {split($0,arr,"/"); print arr[5]}'
```

Where:

- `/avg/` - look for line with the string `avg`
- `split($0,arr,"/")` - split the line using a forward slash (`/`) as the delimiter, place the segments in the `arr[]` array
- `print arr[5]` - print the 5th element of the `arr[]` array

Combining with the `ping`:

```
ping -c 4 google.com | awk '/avg/ {split($0,arr,"/"); print arr[5]}'
66.467
```

And if we need to include the measurement of time (`ms` in this case), we can also print the last field of the line that contains the string `avg`, eg:

```
ping -c 4 google.com | awk '/avg/ {split($0,arr,"/"); print arr[5],$NF}'
66.467 ms
```

**NOTES**:

- OP may need to tweak the `awk` command if their `ping` output is in a different format
- obviously (?) each time the ping is run we're likely to get a slightly different value.
- if OP wants to be 100% certain of the value then the `ping` command output should be saved to a file (or variable) and then run the `awk` command against said file (or variable)